# Is it possible to create a pdf file from base64 string?

Tags: java, pdf, base64

I have a hl7 file which contains a base64 string derived from an encoded pdf.

Is it possible to recreate a pdf from that base64?

```
pdf to base64 --> ok
----------------------------
base64 to pdf --> is this possible?
```

Comment: Short answer is yes, that's kind of the point of base64, converting binary data to and from text

Answer (score 1):

It´s possible. You can use sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
/**
 * Kax7ux
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {     
        String encodedBytes = "yourStringBase64"; 
        try {
            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            byte[] decodedBytes;
            FileOutputStream fop;
            decodedBytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encodedBytes);
            File file = new File("path/file.pdf");
            fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

            fop.write(decodedBytes);

            fop.flush();
            fop.close();
            System.out.println("Created");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Clem You can easy use the **Base64** class from **java.util**

```
   import java.util.Base64;

    public class App 
    {
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {  
            String pdfAsArrayByte = "JVBERi/8KNyAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZS....";

            // Decode the Base64 arrayByte to PDF file
            DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(Base64.getDecoder().decode(pdfAsArrayByte),"application/pdf");

            // The ,source, instance is now a true PDF file
        }
    }
```